# Cannot boot lubuntu from HDD after clean install

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, lubuntu

I have installed lubuntu 17.04 on an old Pentium 4 machine, using a lubuntu live DVD.
After installation I cannot boot the newly installed OS. It says "missing operating system".

It did work after installing lubuntu 12.04, but obviously I'd prefer a newer version.

I tried using (an older version of) boot repair, but without any luck. The summary can be found here http://paste.ubuntu.com/25060051/

Does anyone know why an older OS works, but a newer one doesn't? How can I fix the currently installed OS so I can boot it and use it?

*UPDATE*

Just tried installing 12.04 again and then upgrading to 14.04. When the upgrade was done and I rebooted as instructed, the PC wasn't able to boot again.
I tried Boot Repair again but with no luck.

The message I'm seeing is:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

Comment: I've not had a lot of success with `grub` when I try to boot an OS on a different disc (see lines 6-9 of your disc repair listing). Try installing with `sdb` disconnected, so that you will get a copy of `grub` on `sda`, though there may be other and better ways to achieve this. To boot Windows on `sdb` you will need to change your BIOS boot order, which is not ideal, but I've learned to live with it.

Comment: I just tried this, but to no avail. I still get an error when trying to boot. This is my latest pastebin from boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25063703/ 
I also tried installing 17.04, which didn't boot, then zipping all files of the OS, formatting partition and installing 12.04, which booted, then removed all system files and unzipped the 17.04 zip file, so the MBR remained untouched, but all the files on disk were that of 17.04. Did not work. "Reboot and select proper boot device it says now". Also tried boot repair after that. No luck. I feel like I'm just randomly trying things. :-p

Comment: At a quick glance, everything looks OK: the OS prober is finding the image, and the boot configuration file is roughly what I would have expected. I'll try to go through your logs in more detail tomorrow. I presume your machine is too old to have EFI support in its BIOS, but it's worth checking. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I don't recall any difficulties installing this on an older (non-EFI) laptop.

Comment: It seems the BIOS is from 2002 and I don't see (U)EFI mentioned anywhere in its boot configuration screen. @AFH I appreciate your help!